# Recuperar parâmetro para filtro em SQL: data e hora a cada minutos

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna chamado valores e nela tem as seguintes colunas: ID, VALOR e DATA.

Tenho um `while` em `PHP` que conta 24 horas, logo preciso recuperar os registros de 30 em 30 minutos.

Preciso do parâmetro para consulta 30 em 30 minutos.

Código anterior:

```php
while($cont<=24){
    $conta = $cont -1;
    $conta;
    $hora[$cont]  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+60 min",strtotime($hora[$conta])));
    
    $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM valores where data_hora < '$hora[$cont]' order by id desc limit 1  ");
    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();



    foreach($resultado as $row)
    {
      $nome_equipamento = $row['nome'];
      $valor_equipamento = $row['valor'];

      $data_alarme = $row['data_hora'];

      $data_a = date("H", strtotime($data_alarme));

      if($data_a != $conta){$valor_equipamento = 0;}

      $data_alarme = date("d/m/Y - H:i:s", strtotime($data_alarme));

       
      $cont++;  


    }
  }
```

Como retornar o parâmetro para consulta no SQL, exemplo desejado:

> 2016-08-24 00:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 00:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 01:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fica mais simples com um `loop` para hora e outro para minutos.

Separei uma parte do código em uma função para facilitar o entendimento do código:

```
for($hora= 0; $hora < 24; $hora++){
    $hoje = new DateTime();
    for($minuto = 0; $minuto <= 30; $minuto += 30){
        $data_hora = $hoje->format('Y-m-d') . ' '  // dia mes e ano de hoje
            . str_pad($hora, 2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT)   // hora do primeiro loop (formatado com zero à esquerda)
            . ':' . str_pad($minuto, 2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':00'; // minutos do segundo loop (formatado com zero à esquerda)

        // nota: os segundos estão fixos em 00 (linha acima)
    
        processa_query($data_hora ); // chama a função que irá processar o sql
    }
}

function processa_query($data_hora){
   
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM valores where data_hora < '$data_hora' order by id desc limit 1  ";
    $consulta = $pdo->query($sql);
    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();



    foreach ($resultado as $row) {
        $nome_equipamento = $row['nome'];
        $valor_equipamento = $row['valor'];

        $data_alarme = $row['data_hora'];

        $data_a = date("H", strtotime($data_alarme));

        if ($data_a != $conta) {
            $valor_equipamento = 0;
        }

        $data_alarme = date("d/m/Y - H:i:s", strtotime($data_alarme));
    }
}
```

A função `processa_query` receberá como parâmetro a data atual e a variação a cada 30 minutos. Exemplo dos parâmetros passados na data 24/08/2016:

> 2016-08-24 00:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 00:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 01:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 01:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 02:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 02:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 03:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 03:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 04:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 04:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 05:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 05:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 06:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 06:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 07:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 07:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 08:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 08:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 09:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 09:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 10:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 10:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 11:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 11:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 12:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 12:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 13:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 13:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 14:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 14:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 15:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 15:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 16:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 16:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 17:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 17:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 18:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 18:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 19:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 19:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 20:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 20:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 21:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 21:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 22:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 22:30:00
>
> 2016-08-24 23:00:00
>
> 2016-08-24 23:30:00

Caso eu tenha entendido mal a sua questão é só postar um comentário abaixo que eu atualizo.

Comment: Valeu Allan, perfeito !!!

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o ideal, já que quer consultar de 30 em 30min, é ajustar seu contador para minutos. Por exemplo: 24horas são 1440min, e então passaria a decrementar os minutos ao invés das horas.

No PHP consegue gerar uma data/hora com a função date(). Uma observação é que essa função converte segundos para horas e não minutos para horas, mas para resolver basta colocar dentro da função os minutos multiplicados por 60. Ex.:echo date("h:m:s",(150*60));

Resultado >> 02:30:00

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Amigo.