# Formatar resultado em JSON com os dados retornados a cada 30 minutos

Tags: php, json

Há pouco tempo atrás, fiz esta pergunta: [Recuperar parâmetro para filtro em SQL: data e hora a cada minutos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148783/recuperar-par%C3%A2metro-para-filtro-em-sql-data-e-hora-a-cada-minutos)

Agora preciso que o resultado seja no formato igual JSON ao abaixo:

```
{label:'00:00', y:92 , indexLabel:'92'},
{label:'00:00', y:92 , indexLabel:'92'},
{label:'01:00', y:92 , indexLabel:'92'}
```

Como fazer?

Comment: E qual o problema? O que você fez e qual erro ocorreu?

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor sua resposta?

Comment: Agora o sentido da pergunta mudou completamente, deixou de ser um problema de javascript para ser um problema no back-end PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode tentar o seguinte código:

```
for($hora= 0; $hora < 24; $hora++){
    $hoje = new DateTime();
    for($minuto = 0; $minuto <= 30; $minuto += 30){
        $data_hora = $hoje->format('Y-m-d') . ' '  // dia mes e ano de hoje
            . str_pad($hora, 2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT)   // hora do primeiro loop (formatado com zero à esquerda)
            . ':' . str_pad($minuto, 2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':00'; // minutos do segundo loop (formatado com zero à esquerda)

        // nota: os segundos estão fixos em 00 (linha acima)


        $resultado[] = processa_query($data_hora ); // chama a função que irá processar o sql
    }
}

// monta o resultado em $JSON e exibe o mesmo, o implode junta a array em uma string
echo $JSON = '{ "dados":[' .  implode(', ', $resultado) . ']}';

function processa_query($data_hora){



    $sql = "SELECT valor FROM valores where data_hora < '$data_hora' order by id desc limit 1  ";
    $consulta = $pdo->query($sql);
    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll(3);

    $valor_equipamento = $resultado[0][0];

    // através do explode, separo a data da hora (separados pelo espaço)
    $hora_minuto = explode(' ' ,$data_hora);
    // removo os segundos
    $hora_minuto = substr($hora_minuto[1], 0,5);
    // monto um item o JSON concatenando: 
    // label: recebe a variável $hora_minuto 
    // y: recebe o $valor_equipamento (sem aspas)
    // indexLabel: recebe o $valor_equipamento (com aspas)
    return "{label:'$hora_minuto', y:$valor_equipamento , indexLabel:'$valor_equipamento'}";
}
```

Comment: Duplicou de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148798/3635, se já existia resposta então não duplique por favor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: O correto seria ele editar a pergunta anterior para alterar o resultado de saída? Que antes eram apenas data e hora e agora seria JSON?

Comment: A pergunta foi marcada como duplicata, se você acha que não é então deve votar por reabrir. O que pode ser bem correto já que aqui fala do JSON.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não estou questionando não... só quero entender o que seria melhor para a comunidade... ele deveria alterar a primeira pergunta que desejava saber como retornar as horas... e já tinha sido respondida e abrir outra para formatar a saída com JSON, ou seria melhor ele editar a pergunta?

Comment: Eu entendi, acho que você deveria manter ambas respostas, mas explicar esta aqui melhor e modificar esta pergunta e votar para reabrir, já que aqui é outro problema. O problema que o AP é quem não soube perguntar, pois ele já tinha a resposta, só faltava a parte do JSON, mas ele preferiu repetir o problema. Então para melhor proveito é editar a pergunta mesmo. Claro que isso é opinião minha :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, muito obrigado pela explicação. Para mim que tinha falado com o autor da pergunta pelo chat estava claro, mas realmente a pergunta estava confusa e parecia duplicada. Já fiz a edição... porém ainda não sei ou não tenho privilégio suficiente para votar para fechar ou reabrir. Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: só recomendo que explique o código atual, pois tem a explicação de como fez o 24horas, mas não tem a explicação da concatenação e do implode, só uma dica para enriquecer a resposta ;) ... PS: votei por reabrir.

Comment: Reabri, mas acho que é bom o autor da pergunta ficar mais atento para explicar melhor as próximas duvidas, pois me parece falta de esclarecimento na anterior. (na verdade se já é o que está respondido, não precisava nem reabrir, mas enfim...)

Comment: @Bacco, agradeço ... foi falha minha, pois como falei com ele no chat e ele é um usuário de baixa pontuação, eu deveria ter orientado ele melhor.  Serve de experiência para as próximas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, explicações adicionadas!

Comment: Adicionei um pequeno detalhe